# Forward data in laravel for email content

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to forward my data on Laravel to infrastructure.blade.php when I trigger the send button.

Inside the infrastructure.blade.php I have these codes.

```
@component('mail::message')
# Critical Infrastructure:  Name (want to use {{$infrastructure->name}})

You're receiving this email because our records indicate that the above Infrastructure 
is in critical condition and need to be checked asap.

Click on the button below for more details.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'http://localhost:8000/infrastructures/$infrastructure->id'])
View More!
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('infrastructures', 'infrastructureController');

Route::get('/email', function () {

    Mail::to('example@gmail.com')->send(new ReportInfrastructure());

    Flash::success('Email Sent Successfully. ');

    return redirect(route('infrastructures.index'));
});
```

ReportInfrastructure.php

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.infrastructure');
}
```

show.blade.php I have to following codes,

```
<div class="row" style="padding-left: 20px">
@include('infrastructures.show_fields')
<a href="{{ route('infrastructures.edit', [$infrastructure->id]) }}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
<a href="{{ route('infrastructures.index') }}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
<a href="{{ url('/email') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Send</a>
</div>
```

I recently try having this but no page found.

```
<a href="{{ url('/email',[$infrastructure->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Send</a>
```

Could someone assist me with it, please!

Thanks,

Comment: Please share your `/infrastructures/` route

Comment: @ChristopheHubert. I have edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing nor receiving any arguments between your entities: URL generation, Route, Controller, Mailable.
You need to tell your functions that you need to pass the `$infrastructure`

```
<a href="{{ url('/email',['infrastructure_id' => $infrastructure->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Send</a>
```

```
Route::get('/email/{infrastructure_id}', function ($infrastructure_id) {
    $infrastructure = Infrastructure::find($infrastructure_id);
    Mail::to('tekitaamtk@gmail.com')->send(new ReportInfrastructure($infrastructure));
    Flash::success('Email Sent Successfully. ');
    return redirect(route('infrastructures.index'));
});
```

You will need to accept the `$infrastructure` argument in your `ReportInfrastructure` Class **constructor** to display it in your email - [See the doc here for more details](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#view-data)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. managed to get what I want after I followed your answer. secondly, the URL is not working if I use `{{ $infrastructure->id}}`. How can I address that?